# getting file from sfdc with mule

Tags: salesforce, mule

I need to get file from sfdc and send it to ftp server. I am using mulesoft to connect sfdc.

I have seen below docs in sfdc, but this is like getting content and do mapping and convert to file. Instead of this, I need to get file directly from sfdc and send the file to ftp or email. Any changes in future will be changed in sfdc so that no changes required in mulesoft code.

[image]

[sfdc connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Salesforce+Connector)

EDIT:

Below thread reads the content of attachment, and making it as required file format. But, I am trying to look for directly reading file from sfdc and load the file to local disk.

I don't find any operation in  sfdc connector to get the file from sfdc.

[sfdc forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008rEnIAI)

Comment: Have you checked the Salesforce Connector documentation to check if there's an operation that does what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFDC APIs used to read and write data to Salesforce objects. Usually using SOQL. I do not understand your statement "I need to get a file from SFDC but not reading content". Would you please explain?

The following link list latest Mule SFDC connector APIs. The metadata APIs deals with files instead of SOQL but those files used to read/write your model metadata.

http://mulesoft.github.io/salesforce-connector/6.1.0/mule/sfdc-config.html

Comment: SOQL is fetching data from SFDC, and in mule mapper map it and then create file format in flows. What I am trying to do is get the file directly from sfdc instead of getting content and making file. e.g if there is any file created in sfdc, i need to get that file so that in future if there is any changes in the file will be handled by the sfdc development team.

Comment: I don't this this is how SFDC APIs work. It is just like any database, you need to query it for data.